# OpenCV drawMatches -- queryIdx and trainIdx

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

This is OpenCV's [`drawMatches()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html#drawMatches) function:

```
void drawMatches(Mat img1, vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1,
                 Mat img2, vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2,
                 vector<DMatch> matches, 
                 Mat outImg) //want keypoints1[i] = keypoints2[matches[i]]
```

Notice that `matches` is of type `vector<DMatch>`. Here is the [`DMatch`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#DMatch) constructor:

```
DMatch(int queryIdx, int trainIdx, float distance)
```

Presumably, `queryIdx` is an index into one set of keypoints, and `trainIdx` is an index into the other set of keypoints.

The question: **Is it true that `queryIdx` indexes into `keypoints1`, and `trainIdx` indexes into `keypoints2`? Or, is it the other way around?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That depends on how you get `matches`.

If you call match function in the order:

```
match(descriptor_for_keypoints1, descriptor_for_keypoints2, matches)
```

then `queryIdx` refers to `keypoints1` and `trainIdx` refers to `keypoints2`, or vice versa.

Comment: They should make the function clearer. The interface and language is not consistent.

Comment: totally agree. the naming is super confusing and there is no explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 11):

the variable "*matches*"    is  a   list    of  **DMatch objects**.

If  we  are iterating   over    this    list    of **DMatch objects**,  then    each    item    will    have    the following   attributes:

1. **item.distance**:  This    attribute   gives   us  the distance    between the descriptors.    A   lower distance  indicates   a   better  match.
2. **item.trainIdx**:  This    attribute   gives   us  the index   of  the descriptor  in  the list    of  train descriptors   (in our case,   it’s    the list    of  descriptors in  the img2).
3. **item.queryIdx**:  This    attribute   gives   us  the index   of  the descriptor  in  the list    of  query descriptors   (in our case,   it’s    the list    of  descriptors in  the img1).
4. **item.imgIdx**:    This    attribute   gives   us  the index   of  the train   image.

Comment: What is imgIdx? I can't find a discussion of it.

Comment: Same here, can't find an explanation what is `imgIdx` - there are only two images I compare

Comment: How would I find an Y coordinate of a match in an image?

Comment: @ed22 You use either `trainIdx` or `queryIdx` to index into either `keypoints1` or `keypoints2`, extract the `pt` attribute and get the Y coordinate that way.