# OpenCV: Fitting an object into a scene using homography and perspective transform in Java

Tags: java, opencv, feature-detection, homography

I'm implementing using Java the OpenCV tutorial for finding an object in a scene using homography http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

Below is my implementation, where img1 is the scene and img2 is the object

```
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);

    //set up img1 (scene)
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    //calculate descriptor for img1
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    //set up img2 (template)
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    //calculate descriptor for img2
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    //match 2 images' descriptors
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2,matches);

    //calculate max and min distances between keypoints
    double max_dist=0;double min_dist=99;

    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
    for(int i=0;i<descriptors1.rows();i++)
    {
        double dist = matchesList.get(i).distance;
        if (dist<min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist>max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    //set up good matches, add matches if close enough
    LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    MatOfDMatch gm = new MatOfDMatch();
    for (int i=0;i<descriptors2.rows();i++)
    {
        if(matchesList.get(i).distance<3*min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
        }
    }
    gm.fromList(good_matches);

    //put keypoints mats into lists
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints1_List = keypoints1.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints2_List = keypoints2.toList();

    //put keypoints into point2f mats so calib3d can use them to find homography
    LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    for(int i=0;i<good_matches.size();i++)
    {
        objList.addLast(keypoints2_List.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        sceneList.addLast(keypoints1_List.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
    }
    MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
    MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
    obj.fromList(objList);
    scene.fromList(sceneList);

    //output image
    Mat outputImg = new Mat();
    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, gm, outputImg, Scalar.all(-1), Scalar.all(-1), drawnMatches,Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    //run homography on object and scene points
    Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene,Calib3d.RANSAC, 5);
    Mat tmp_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

    //get corners from object
    tmp_corners.put(0, 0, new double[] {0,0});
    tmp_corners.put(1, 0, new double[] {img2.cols(),0});
    tmp_corners.put(2, 0, new double[] {img2.cols(),img2.rows()});
    tmp_corners.put(3, 0, new double[] {0,img2.rows()});

    Core.perspectiveTransform(tmp_corners,scene_corners, H);


    Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(0,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(1,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(1,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(2,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(2,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(3,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(3,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(0,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
```

The program is able to calculate and display feature points from both images. However, the scene_corners returned are 4 points in a close cluster (small green blob) 
where they are supposed to represent the 4 corners of the perspective projection of the object onto the scene. I checked double checked to make sure my program is as close to the c++ implementation as possible. What might be causing this?

I checked the homography matrix and it seems the corner coordinates are skewed by 2 very big results from the matrix. Is the homography matrix incorrectly calculated?

I'd appreciate any input, thanks.

Update:

I played about with the filter threshold for good matches and found that 2.75*min_dist seems to work well with this set of images. I can now get good matches with zero outliers. However, the bounding box is still wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qjmN.jpg

How do I know what value of threshold to use for best matches and how does the homography relate to them? Why was 3*min_dist used in the example?

Comment: Please give a look at section 7.1 of this paper: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf  

It's about an effective way to do the "Keypoint Matching" without using the distance measure that does not perform well since some of the descriptors are much more discriminative than others.  I think that will give you better results. If you have questions on the implementation of the "Ratio Test" I can help. If results do not improve maybe you have to use another descriptor, eg SIFT.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to the findhomography function, I don't think the problem is with the matches but the transformation matrix produced was wrong. This causes the perspective transform giving the wrong result as well. See this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771285/opencv-how-to-use-findhomography-correctly

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem and use homography correctly while investigating index out of bounds errors. It turns out when I added my good matches to my object and scene lists, I swapped round the query and train indices

```
objList.addLast(keypoints2_List.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
sceneList.addLast(keypoints1_List.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
```

According to this question [OpenCV drawMatches -- queryIdx and trainIdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318853/opencv-drawmatches-queryidx-and-trainidx) , since I called

```
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2,matches);
```

with descriptor1 first then descriptor2, the correct indices should be:

```
objList.addLast(keypoints2_List.get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
sceneList.addLast(keypoints1_List.get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
```

where queryIdx refers to keypoints1_List and trainIdx refers to keypoints2_List.

Here is an example result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakZP.png

Comment: it is still crashing, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm also implementing a 2D homography in java and I also found the [OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) then your question.

I don't think it'll enhance your results but in the OpenCV tutorial when they compute the min and max distance, they loop with *descriptors_object.rows* and in your code you do with *descriptors1.rows()* which is the scene descriptor and not the object descriptor.

Edit: Just also noticed the same with the matcher. For you:

- img1/descriptor1 -> Scene
- img2/descriptor2 -> the object to find

In the tutorial:

```
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );
```

But in your code:

```
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2,matches);
```

And Javadoc:

```
void org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.match(Mat queryDescriptors, Mat trainDescriptors, MatOfDMatch matches)
```