# python pickldump error. Serialization of stereo image matches do not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pickle

I want to calculate the matches between 2 stereo images

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
      matches = bf.match(des_left, des_right)
```

like in this link: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

In the end, I want to save it in a pickle dump:

```
 with open(stereo_matches_path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({'kp': kp_left[matches[:,0], :], 'des': des_left[matches[:,1], :], 'xyz': xyz}, f)
```

But I can't, I always get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

---

Edit:

kp_left are the key points with the format , like this `array([[ 3515.53686523,  1868.1932373 ], [ 3005.02954102,  2513.69335938],...])`

If we are iterating over this list of DMatch objects, then each item will have the following attributes: ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318853/opencv-drawmatches-queryidx-and-trainidx))

- item.distance: This attribute gives us the distance between the
  descriptors. A lower distance indicates a better match.
- item.trainIdx: This attribute gives us the index of the descriptor in
  the list of train descriptors (in our case, it’s the list of
  descriptors in the img2).
- item.queryIdx: This attribute gives us the    index of the descriptor
  in the list of query descriptors (in our    case, it’s the list of
  descriptors in the img1).
- item.imgIdx: This    attribute gives us the index of the train image.

How to give the keypoints all indices from matches?

Comment: The page you linked says that `matches` is a list of DMatch objects. So you need to index `matches` using simple integer indices, or use slice notation to get a sublist.

Comment: I mean, I use slice notation.

this works but not for all
kp_left[matches[0].queryIdx, :], 'des': des_left[matches[0].queryIdx, :]